# Zend_Feed_Reader exception: Read timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: zend-framework, rss-reader, atom-feed, zend-feed

I am using `Zend_Feed_Reader` to read feeds but I have a problem. At some feeds, I get this exception: `Read timed out after 10 seconds` and I want to reduce that time.

So in the case `Zend_Feed_Reader` can't read that feed in 4 seconds threw this exception. I don't want him to try to read for 10 seconds, if he can't read it in 4 seconds give it up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like many ZF components, `Zend_Feed_Reader` uses `Zend_Http_Client` for its communication with external services, and you can provide it a pre-configured instance of this class for custom functionality (such as using a HTTP proxy, custom useragent, or in your case, timeout):

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client(null, array(
    'timeout' => 4
));
Zend_Feed_Reader::setHttpClient($client);
```

then just use the component as you were before:

```
$feed = Zend_Feed_Reader::import('http://example.com/some-feed.rss');
```